# Trying to install Kong using the Helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kong-ingress

Trying to install Kong using the Helm chart using the following command using this [post](https://itnext.io/kong-proof-of-concept-using-minikube-5f8ca932083f)

```
>helm install --version 0.26.1 --name kong stable/kong --namespace kong --set ingressController.enabled=true --set image.tag=1.4 --set admin.useTLS=false
```

But getting the following error

Error: unknown flag: --name

**Solution I tried**

Removed  -- name then I am getting the following error

Error: failed to download "stable/kong" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In helm version 3 `--name` flag is removed.  You can give a name without `--name` flag as shown below

```
helm repo add kong https://charts.konghq.com

helm repo update

helm install --version 1.7.0 kong kong/kong  --namespace kong --set ingressController.enabled=true --set image.tag=1.4 --set admin.useTLS=false
```

Find more details [here](https://hub.helm.sh/charts/kong/kong)